# How can I add a responsive image to a table cell in materialize?

Tags: css, materialize

This shows my image in a small circle:

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col s1">
    <img src="images/img1.jpg" alt="" class="circle responsive-img">
  </div>
</div>
```

Now, I want to add the same image, in a table cell (`td`) and show it in a circle of the same size.

Should I copy/paste the above code as is inside the `td` ? It seems too verbose. Is there a simpler way?

Note: I know that a solution could be to write some custom css, but the reason why I use a css framework is to not write css, especially for common things like this.

Answer (score 2):

You can just add the classes directly to the table elements like:

```html
    <tr class="row">
      <td class="col s2">
        <img src="src" alt="" class="circle responsive-img" />
      </td>
    </tr>
```

Here is an example:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css" />

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Item Name</th>
      <th>Item Price</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr class="row">
      <td class="col s1">
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/4iGwt.jpg?s=328&g=1" alt="" class="circle responsive-img" />
      </td>
      <td>Eclair</td>
      <td>$0.87</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Alan</td>
      <td>Jellybean</td>
      <td>$3.76</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jonathan</td>
      <td>Lollipop</td>
      <td>$7.00</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Indeed, this works and is less verbose, as I asked. I wonder, why I can't find this example (adding `row`,`col` classes on `tr`,`td` ) anywhere. Is there some other common practice that is normally preferred (e.g writing css or adding `row`,`col` divs inside the cell as described in my question)?

Comment: @MarinosAn You are totally right it's not a best practice since a `tr` and `td` can't be really associated to a `.row` and `.col` class. However it won't impact the original behaviour of the table so using it isn't a problem at all. But I would encourage to add a custom class `.avatar` on the cells to easily customise them for other purposes. See [an example here](https://jsfiddle.net/ztonk4rd/5/).

Comment: in your example the first column needs to be far away from the second, in order for the image to have a visible size. If the first column comes close to the second, you can barely see the image.

Comment: @MarinosAn Right in this case I recommand you to add the additionnal custom class  with a `min-width` property like https://jsfiddle.net/dxz3nofp/2/

Comment: @MarinosAn Any questions on that? Do you need another example?

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to mix the grid system with the table. This will suffice:

```
<img height="30" width="30" class="circle" src="https://picsum.photos/50" alt="My Circular Image">
```

The `.circle` class in materialize just adds this CSS:

```
.circle {
   border-radius: 50%;
}
```

The `responsive-img` class add this CSS:

```
img.responsive-img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

This is to stop images breaking out of containers, and is of no help to you here. What you need to do is use a square image and control the height of the image inline, as shown above.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/doughballs/pen/abJGgvq).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a button circle and set image with tag `responsive-img`, example:

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Image</th>
            <th>Item Name</th>
            <th>Item Price</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <a class="btn-floating waves-effect waves-light btn-tiny white">
              <img src="https://materializecss.com/images/yuna.jpg" alt="" class="circle responsive-img">
            </a>
          </td>
          <td>Jellybean</td>
          <td>$3.76</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Jonathan</td>
          <td>Lollipop</td>
          <td>$7.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <a class="btn-floating waves-effect waves-light btn-tiny white">
              <img src="https://materializecss.com/images/yuna.jpg" alt="" class="circle responsive-img">
            </a>
          </td>
          <td>Lollipop</td>
          <td>$7.00</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```